# NullPointerException in Java TableRowSorter

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, listener

I made a jtable for the list of chemicals in the inventory where I can sort each columns using the following code (chemicalTable is the name of the jTable):

```
chemicalTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter1 
      = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(chemicalTable.getModel());
chemicalTable.setRowSorter(sorter1);
```

Then I used a jTextfield to create a searchbox with a keyTyped Listener so that whenever the user types a certain character the table refreshes. And it usually works.

I used this code in the keyTypedListener for the searchbox:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) chemicalTable.getModel();

str = searchChemicalText.getText();

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/chemical inventory";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error Occurred.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        int ctr = 0;


        while (ctr < chemicalTable.getRowCount()) {
            chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(null, ctr, 0);
            chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(null, ctr, 1);
            chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(null, ctr, 2);
            ctr++;

        }

        int count = 0;

        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "Select * FROM chemicallist where name_of_reagent like '%" + str + "%'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            if (rs.next()) {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String qty = null, qtyunit = null, chemstate = null, reagentName = null;

                    reagentName = rs.getString("name_of_reagent");
                    qty = rs.getString("quantity");
                    qtyunit = rs.getString("quantity_unit");
                    chemstate = rs.getString("state");
                    chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(reagentName, count, 0);
                    chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(qty + " " + qtyunit, count, 1);
                    chemicalTable.getModel().setValueAt(chemstate, count, 2);



                    if (count + 1 > chemicalTable.getRowCount() - 1) {
                        dm.setRowCount(chemicalTable.getRowCount() + 1);
                        dm.fireTableRowsInserted(0, 5);


                    }
                    count++;


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error Occurred.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        }
```

My problem is: Whenever I sort first any columns (col1, col2, or col3) and I insert a character in the searchbox, I got this error message:

"Exception occurred during event dispatching:
Java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: a better title describing a summary of your problem will attract more help :)

Comment: It had to be one of the least informative titles ever. Next, show the actual line that throws the NPE (NullPointerException).

Comment: If that code is in a KeyListener, you look to be in trouble. First off, I would not recommend that you use a KeyListener with a JTextField. Next, you are doing a lot of long-running processing on the Swing event thread, and this risks causing a threading error. If your NPE occurs intermittently and unexpectedly, then likely it is due to a threading problem.

Comment: Should I remove the Keytyped Listener in the searchbox? What should I use instead of the Keylistener.

Comment: @user2360597: What is the goal of the code? Why listen to the JTextField's key presses in the first place? Why tie it to a database query?

Comment: Like every searchbox do, to view the data, you are looking for, inside the table faster and more easily (Sorry for the bad English)

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not possible to debug your code fragments, several things stand out:

- In the same section, you reference the `TableModel` as `dm` and `chemicalTable.getModel()`; use a single reference or verify that they refer to the same instance.
- Instead of meddling with `setRowCount()`, use one of the `addRow()` methods.
- The `DefaultTableModel` methods that alter the model fire the correct event for you and the table will automatically update itself accordingly; you shouldn't have to do this yourself.

Comment: or possible to test by `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`